# Having trouble read some arabic from text file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Im trying to do a project for my school and i need to get arabic sentences from text files but it doesnt detects the text code worked with latin words.

tried to change the encoding but still didnt worked.
Heres my code

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
image=Image.open('gazete2.png')
text=image_to_string(image,lang='urd')
print(text)



file1 = open('deneme.txt','r+', encoding="utf-16")
lines = file1.readlines()
for row in lines:

    if row.find(text) != -1:
        print((row))
```

Comment: Maybe the `codec` libary can help you ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html)), for some example see [this link](https://pymotw.com/2/codecs/#working-with-files). If that doesn't help i would need a more concrete string example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read Arabic text from a file using Python, you will need to make sure that the file is encoded in a Unicode format such as UTF-8, and that your Python code is able to handle Unicode characters. You can read the contents of a file into a string variable using the open() and read() methods, like this:

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    arabic_text = f.read()
```

Once you have read the text into a string variable, you can use string methods and operations in Python to manipulate the text as needed. For example, you can use the encode() method to encode the text in a different format, or you can use string slicing and indexing to extract specific parts of the text.

It's also worth noting that the way Arabic text is displayed on screen can depend on the font that is used. If you are having trouble displaying the text properly, you may need to experiment with different fonts to find one that supports the Arabic characters you are trying to display.